# Download using Google Drive API NO ERROR but NOT RESULT

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to download a file using this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get).  I made some modification.
But when I'm trying to run the file, it does not give me error but no result too. 
It can get the downloadUrl of the file and it also satisfies this condition:

```
 if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      echo "i'm here..";
      return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
 }
```

What am I missing here?  How to process this returned value? 
**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Use [version 2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) of the API, there is a PHP example there you can use.

Comment: Okay sir. Thanks for the reply. But I'm getting this error:
**Class 'Google_HttpRequest' not found**
What to include in order for this to work?  Do you have any idea why I can't be able to download the file? is the download codes is only true if the file is in the root? or it will also work if the file is in the parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading make sure you specify the encryption type. Otherwise it would give this error.